# How do I adjust my chrome extension's manifest.json's "matches" key dynamically by pulling its value from an external source (database)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a chrome extension and I'd like to only allow my content_scripts to be run only when the user access certain pages.

Hard-coding the webpages where it can be accessed doesn't seem to be the proper practice. How can I modify my manifest.json script to pull the content_script "matches" from an external source?

Answer (score 2):

You should write something like `"content_scripts": [{"matches": ["*://*/*"]` in your manifest. To have ability execute scripts an all pages. In extension code track user navigation and when user navigates to specific page (which you interested in), insert scripts to it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like

```
"content_scripts": {"matches": ["http://*/", "https://*/"]}
```

Then in your script, you can load a list of external match patterns to check against in your script.

I did this in a recent extension by putting the list of match patterns for my site list in a json file, and then loading its contents into localStorage for consumption by the filter.

I wrote up a a [walkthrough of the extension source code](http://jdstraughan.com/2013/02/07/nonews-part-2-the-source/), it may help you see how I accomplished something similar.